# Rebase onto another branch and remove changes of old one

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, rebase

I have:

```
A--B             (master)
    \    
     C--D        (bad-branch)
         \
          E--F   (my-branch)
```

The result i want:

```
A--B             (master)
    \    
     E--F        (my-branch)
```

I tried rebase `my-branch` onto `master` but when i push `my-branch` to repo, it's merged with the origin and the bad commits with the changes come back.

Comment: may you have to delete all the commits and yeah that will be all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rebase a number of commits onto another branch using the `--onto` flag.

First make sure you have the branch checked out you want to rebase (not strictly necessary as you can provide that arg to rebase, but step-by-step is often clearer and easier).

```
git checkout my-branch
# or git switch my-branch
```

Rebase the top two commits onto master:

```
git rebase --onto master @~2
```

An alternative to counting the number of commits is to just use the bad branch name as a ref:

```
git rebase --onto master bad-branch
```

In your example `@~2` on `my-branch` is the same commit as `bad-branch` so they could be used interchangeably.

Comment: Also worth mentioning : `git rebase -i master`

Comment: `git rebase --onto master bad-branch` just return "Current branch my-branch is up to date.". But after undo the last unsuccessful rebase, the `git rebase --onto master @~2
` was the one.

Comment: @AndréWalker: That means `bad-branch` was not pointing to the same place as `@~2`. If the branches were set up the same as your diagram, there should be no difference between the two commands you ran. The last argument to `rebase` needs to be the parent of the first commit you want to move to master.